# output a list of all the methods, and the number of bytes in a java class file?

Tags: java, class, bytecode

I want to know how to get the list of all the methods and the number of bytes for each method in a class file.

For example :

I want to have a main source code where it can parse few .class files through cmd line arguments and get the above mentioned details of each classes.

```
    javac myapp classFile1.class classFile2.class ...
```

Please Note : I know the list of method can be taken through `javap className.class`

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with? Note: the actual methods loaded and their size  in memory is likely to be very different. e.g. most methods will use much more memory than the byte code suggest esp once it is compiled.

Comment: @Peter well sir, this isnt too complicated or advance as you think. i want to get the list of methods in a .class file and the number of bytes used for each methods. for example we can return all the methods inside a particular class through **getMethods()** function.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It is possible, but there's probably a better way to do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: @Antimony my assignment sir :(

Comment: If there is a problem which makes no sense, there is a good chance it is homework.

Comment: Have you tried Objectweb ASM yet? If you have to do it in Java code, that's the way to go.

Comment: @Antimony uhh no sir,  if my question is not clear to you, is it fine if i send you the doc file which elaborates my question ?

Comment: Getting a list of methods [is easy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--). When it comes to “the number of bytes making up the compiled JVM for each method”, the first obstacle is that the phrase doesn’t make any sense. What is “the compiled JVM for each method”? Are you talking about runtime data inside the JVM or are you still talking about the class file and the word “JVM” is just misleading here? There are different ways to count bytes of a method, look at instructions only, include the metadata or even referenced constant values from the pool…

Comment: @Holger [this doc will help you to understand my question i guess ](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4fFFCbSoKDrUTdweTEzdHIzdjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I can’t access that document. But generally, you should try to include all relevant information into your question.

Comment: i can mail to you, if you prefer sir !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a homework assignment, the particular constraints of your class are important. For example, are you allowed to use libraries or are you expected to write your own classfile parser? If the later, then you just need to read the JVM specification and write a parser for it.

Assuming you are allowed to use libraries, I'd recommend using Objectweb ASM. This will save you from dealing with low level details of the classfile format and having to write a parser.

Looking at [ClassReader.java](http://websvn.ow2.org/filedetails.php?repname=asm&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fasm%2Fsrc%2Forg%2Fobjectweb%2Fasm%2FClassReader.java), the size of the bytecode is not directly exposed to client code. However, `readLabel` is always called with `codeLength + 1` at the beginning of `readCode`. Therefore, if you subclass `ClassReader` and override `readLabel`, you can get the length of the bytecode for each method.

You'll also want to create a `MethodVistor` and override `visitMethodInsn` to get the invoke instructions required for the later parts of the assignment.

Comment: This was helpful Sir :)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to run javap

```
javap -c -v -p -cp . classFile1
```

This will dump out all the methods and the byte code with the length of the method.

e.g.

```
$ javap -c -v -p -cp . java.lang.Void
Classfile jar:file:/opt/jdk1.8.0_51/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/lang/Void.class
  Last modified 08-Jun-2015; size 454 bytes
  MD5 checksum 8a3bdf282569bff4cd7c5fc24cbaee83
  Compiled from "Void.java"
public final class java.lang.Void
  minor version: 0
  major version: 52
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#18         // java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = String             #19            // void
   #3 = Methodref          #20.#21        // java/lang/Class.getPrimitiveClass:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
   #4 = Fieldref           #5.#22         // java/lang/Void.TYPE:Ljava/lang/Class;
   #5 = Class              #23            // java/lang/Void
   #6 = Class              #24            // java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               TYPE
   #8 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/Class;
   #9 = Utf8               Signature
  #10 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/Class<Ljava/lang/Void;>;
  #11 = Utf8               <init>
  #12 = Utf8               ()V
  #13 = Utf8               Code
  #14 = Utf8               LineNumberTable
  #15 = Utf8               <clinit>
  #16 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #17 = Utf8               Void.java
  #18 = NameAndType        #11:#12        // "<init>":()V
  #19 = Utf8               void
  #20 = Class              #25            // java/lang/Class
  #21 = NameAndType        #26:#27        // getPrimitiveClass:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
  #22 = NameAndType        #7:#8          // TYPE:Ljava/lang/Class;
  #23 = Utf8               java/lang/Void
  #24 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #25 = Utf8               java/lang/Class
  #26 = Utf8               getPrimitiveClass
  #27 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
{
  public static final java.lang.Class<java.lang.Void> TYPE;
    descriptor: Ljava/lang/Class;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_FINAL
    Signature: #10                          // Ljava/lang/Class<Ljava/lang/Void;>;

  private java.lang.Void();
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: aload_0
         1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
         4: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 49: 0

  static {};
    descriptor: ()V
    flags: ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=1, locals=0, args_size=0
         0: ldc           #2                  // String void
         2: invokestatic  #3                  // Method java/lang/Class.getPrimitiveClass:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;
         5: putstatic     #4                  // Field TYPE:Ljava/lang/Class;
         8: return
      LineNumberTable:
        line 44: 0
}
SourceFile: "Void.java"
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't directly tell you the size of each method's bytecode. It only shows the offset of each instruction, but you'd have to know the size of the final instruction to compute the total. Other tools like Krakatau can tell you the size of the bytecode directly though. But that's all irrelevant since the question is asking for programmatic access anyway.

Comment: @Antimony you can run javap from a program and you can use ASM is you really want to, but since RETURN is always 1 byte (as are all the RETURN instructions), I don't think adding 1 to the last instruction count is so hard.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: the last instruction doesn’t have to be a `return`. It could also be, for example, `athrow`, `goto` or `goto_w`…

Comment: Or even a tableswitch/lookupswitch, which require complex parsing to determine the actual size. Also, while you could run javap as a shell command and then write a parser for the output, that's A) way more complicated and difficult than necessary and B) will give incorrect results for some classfiles because Javap's output is NOT designed to be machine parseable and in general doesn't have a parseable grammar.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you for your effort Sir, but i need to access this information through programmatic language. I do the have the knowledge of bytecode, but accessing it and getting information through programmatic language is my problem !!

Comment: @TRAX I suggest you have a look at a library like Object Web's ASM